# C++ How can I fill an array of class 1 with objects of class 2?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to C++ programming and trying to learn how to add objects of a 'hunters' class to an array of the 'World' class. I've added an array to the 'World' class, which should store the 'Hunter' objects.
With the '.createHunters()' function I've created a hunter array in the 'world' class which holds the hunter objects and tried to pass it on to the hunters-array in the 'world' class. Here are my classes and main function:

```
WORLD HEADER 


#ifndef WORLD_H
#define WORLD_H
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class World
{
    public:
        World(int x, int y);
        void printWorld();
        void createHunters();
        virtual ~World();

    protected:

    private:
        int arrLength, arrWidth;
        int arrWorld[1][1];
        int arrHunters[8];

};

#endif // WORLD_H

-----


WORLD SOURCE


#include "World.h"
#include "Hunter.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

World::World(int x, int y) //constructor
{
    arrLength = x;
    arrWidth = y;
    arrWorld[arrLength][arrWidth]; //pass on size of array

    int k=0;

    for(int i=0; i<arrLength; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<arrWidth; j++){
            arrWorld[i][j]=k;
        }
    }
}

void World::printWorld()
{
    for(int i=0; i<arrLength; i++){ //print arrWorld
        for (int j=0; j<arrWidth; j++){
            cout << arrWorld[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void World::createHunters()
{
    class Hunters;
    Hunter Hunters[8];

    for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
        Hunters[i].addPoints(i+1);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
        arrHunters[i] = Hunters[i];
    }
}

World::~World()
{
    //dtor
}

-----

HUNTER HEADER 


#ifndef HUNTER_H
#define HUNTER_H
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Hunter
{
    public:
        Hunter();
        virtual void addPoints(int a);
        virtual void printHunter();
        virtual ~Hunter();

    protected:

    private:
        int Hunternumber;
        int lifePoints;
        int gamePoints;
};

#endif // HUNTER_H

-----

HUNTER SOURCE


#include "Hunter.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Hunter::Hunter()
{
    cout << "Hunter " << Hunternumber << " constructed." << endl;
}

void Hunter::addPoints(int a)
{
    Hunternumber=a;
    lifePoints=5;
    gamePoints=0;

    cout << "added Points to Hunter " << Hunternumber << "/ LifePoints: " << lifePoints << "/ GamePoints: " << gamePoints << endl;
}

void Hunter::printHunter()
{
    cout << "created Hunter " << Hunternumber << "/ LifePoints: " << lifePoints << "/ GamePoints: " << gamePoints << endl;
}

Hunter::~Hunter()
{
    cout << "destructed Hunter " << Hunternumber << endl;
}

-----

MAIN-FUNCTION


#include <iostream>
#include "World.h"
#include "Hunter.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int length, width;

    cout << "Enter length of Map: " << endl; //get length of Map
    cin >> length;

    cout << "Enter width of Map: " << endl; //get width of Map
    cin >> width;

    class Wrld1; //creating World class
    World Wrld1(length, width); //adding the size to created World array

    Wrld1.printWorld();

    Wrld1.createHunters();
```

I'm still at the beginning of the game and I just can't get it right. Any ideas? What can I do to make this run, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A Hunter is not an int, so you can't put it in an int[] array. What are you trying to do with that array?

Comment: `arrWorld[arrLength][arrWidth]` in your code doesn't do what you probably think it does.

Comment: Sure it is, it just doesn't do anything useful :)

Comment: @DanM. that isn't a definition, so it's ok, so long as x and y are both 0

Comment: @Caleth well, it's not really OK judging by the following loop ;P Someone needs to read a good book/tutorial on C arrays (and ditch them for vector).

Comment: There are multiple fundamental problems with the shown code. Arrays don't work like that in C++. `arrWorld` is a declared as an 1x1 array and that's what it will always be. Writing   `arrWorld[arrLength][arrWidth]` somewhere in your code doesn't transform it into a differently-sized array. C++ does not work this way. You need to learn how to correctly use `std::vector`s. That's one of several multiple issues here. Please see your C++ textbook for more information.

Comment: @DanM. **it's ok, so long as x and y are both 0** It's undefined before the loop if they aren't

Answer (score 1):

`int arrHunters[8]` is 8 `int` objects in a contiguous block. You can't put `Hunter` objects there.

`int arrWorld[1][1];` is 1 `int` object with an annoying syntax. You can't enlarge it at runtime.

If you want an array of `Hunter` objects in `World`, the definition of `Hunter` must precede the definition of `World`

If you want to resize things at runtime, use `std::vector`.

```
#ifndef WORLD_H
#define WORLD_H
#include "Hunter.h"
#include <array>
#include <vector>

class World
{
    public:
        World(int x, int y);
        void printWorld();

    protected:

    private:
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> arrWorld;
        std::array<Hunter, 8> arrHunter;

};

#endif // WORLD_H

#include "World.h"

#include <iostream>

World::World(int x, int y) //constructor
 : arrWorld(x, std::vector<int>(y, 0)),
   arrHunter{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }
{ }

void World::printWorld()
{
    for(std::vector<int> & col : arrWorld){ //print arrWorld
        for (int value : col){
            std::cout << value << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You don't need to (and shouldn't) declare a class with the same name as a local variable that you are about to declare. (i.e. drop `class Hunters;`, `class Wrld;`)

You shouldn't use members before you have initialised them. Your program has undefined behaviour because of

```
Hunter::Hunter()
{
    cout << "Hunter " << Hunternumber /* using an uninitialised value is undefined */ << " constructed." << endl;
}
```

You should probably move the logic of `Hunter::addPoints` into it's constructor.

```
#ifndef HUNTER_H
#define HUNTER_H

class Hunter
{
    public:
        Hunter(int a);
        void printHunter();

    protected:

    private:
        int Hunternumber;
        int lifePoints = 5;
        int gamePoints = 0;
};

#endif // HUNTER_H

#include "Hunter.h"
#include <iostream>

Hunter::Hunter(int a) : Hunternumber(a) { }

void Hunter::printHunter()
{
    std::cout << "created Hunter " << Hunternumber << "/ LifePoints: " << lifePoints << "/ GamePoints: " << gamePoints << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three major things it seems you need to do.

The first is to change World's `int arrHunters[8];` to `Hunter arrHunters[8];` You want an array of hunters, not an array of numbers.

Next, so that World.h knows what the heck a hunter is, at the top of World.h, you need to `#include "Hunter.h"`

Brief tangent: You're using `class World;` and `class Hunter;` kinda weird, but I'm going to assume someone taught it to you that way, and I won't judge. What I want to say is how I learned it: If two .h documents both reference one another, they get into an argument over which one has to compile first. Their argument is most quickly and cleanly resolved by putting `class World;` at the top of the world document, and `class Hunter;` at the top of the hunter document, ABOVE all the include statements, where the compiler will get to see them before working out who is referencing who. The compiler is then pre-warned each word represents a class, and will know what to do if it sees 'World' or 'Hunter' and it hasn't completely finished reading the relevant .h file for that class yet.

Moving on, you made a bit of a mistake later on caused by capitalization and plurals (and by having your `class` statements hidden inside functions and not in any more sensible areas). The mistake was in following function:

```
void World::createHunters()
{
    class Hunters;
    Hunter Hunters[8];

    for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
        Hunters[i].addPoints(i+1);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
        arrHunters[i] = Hunters[i];
    }
}
```

Can you see it? It's right at the beginning. You accidentally wrote `class Hunters;` instead of `class Hunter;` "Hunters" is actually your variable name. You can help yourself out by always keeping your variables starting with a lowercase letter. So:

```
class Hunter;
Hunter Hunters[8]; //Change this to Hunter hunters[8]; and update everywhere else accordingly.
```

The above is considered more visually distinct, as it helps you mentally differentiate between capitalized classes and lowercase members/variables.

See if those changes get you started on resolving the rest of the code, you're doing fine!